# Python : ENUM class elements are not reachable for built-in dir() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, enums

I am trying to get the **ENUM** class variables using the built-in **dir**.
For normal class we get the following result,

```
from enum import Enum
class foo(Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

>>> dir(foo)
['__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

But if I tweak this class a little bit to get the dictionary values using dot operator as below,

```
class foo(Enum):
    class DotDict(dict):
        # Use this to access the dictionary elements using dot notation
        def __getattr__(*args):
            val = dict.get(*args)
            return DotDict(val) if type(val) is dict else val
        __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
        __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

    # class variables
    a = DotDict({'index': 1, 'city': {'name': 'NY', 'len': 2}})
    b = DotDict({'index': 2, 'city': {'name': 'London', 'len': 6}})
    c = DotDict({'index': 3, 'city': {'name': 'Delhi', 'len': 5}})
```

I get following result with no class variable included,

```
>>> dir(foo)
['DotDict', '__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
```

One strange thing here is I can still access class variables like below,

```
>>> foo.a.index
1

>>> foo.b.city.name
London
```

I dont know the exact reason why the class variable is not reachable for class object. Is there any way we can get the entire list of class variable for above class like we get using ***dir*** built-in?

Comment: `dir(foo.DotDict) `

Comment: Nice finding @SmartManoj. But any explanation why the variables are acting as class variable of **DotDict** instead of **foo**?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in the early 3.x line, `dir()` became implementable as the `__dir__` method on a class, and `Enum` takes advantage of that to only show the four `__xxx__` attributes and any members.

The reason that `a`, `b`, and `c` are not showing up in `dir(foo)` is because they are not members, and they are not members because `DotDict.__getattr__()` is broken.

The appropriate response from `__getattr__` for missing attributes is raising an `AttributeError`, but yours is instead returning the `DotDict` instance and the search name, as can be seen when a `print()` is added:

```
>>> a.__get__
({'a': 1}, '__get__')
```

This is important because descriptors are not converted into members, and the presence of  `__get__`, `__set__`, or `__delete__` is indicative of a descriptor.

---

**TL;DR**

Fix your `__getattr__` and everything should work as intended.